# Как убрать пунктир из фона QScrollBar

Tags: c++, qt

Собственно, вопрос в заголовке, вот картинка:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Используете QSS?

Answer (score 0):

Установите цвет/бордер ползунку скроллбара:

```
QScrollBar::handle:vertical {
  background: #СССССС;
  border: 1px solid #C4CBD5;
}

QScrollBar::handle:vertical:hover{
  background: #CCCCCC;
}
```

Comment: Это не решает проблему. А hover вообще регулировать поведение объекта, когда на него наводят курсор мыши